# How to import and use variables from a config/param file in a shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

My `/home/s/project/bin/FileOperation.sh` file is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
/home/s/project/Param/Param_File.config
current=$(dirname $0)
echo $current
echo 'hello'
echo $RootDir
echo $message
```

My `/home/s/project/Param/Param_File.config` file is:

```
RootDir=/home/s/project
message=hello
```

When I execute the above shell script I get below output:

```
.

hello
```

How can I get the values of `$RootDir` and `$message` printed?

Is there any shortcut way to import a config file instead of writing `/home/s/project/Param/Param_File.config` in shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

. /home/s/project/Param/Param_File.config
current=$(dirname $0)
echo $current
echo 'hello'
echo $RootDir
echo $message
```

---

The dot (`.`) tells the shell to execute the file as a script in the current environment (thus the environment changes are effective). See e.g. [here](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/dot.1.asp). You must ensure the executed file is a valid script.

Without the dot(`.`) the script is run in a new process, which can't alter it's parent environment.

---

The relevant part of the documentation:

> . name [arg ...]
>
> If name is a function defined with the function name
>   reserved word syntax, the function is executed in the current
>   environment (as if it had been defined with the name() syntax.)
>   Otherwise if name refers to a file, the file is read in its entirety
>   and the commands are executed in the current shell environment. The
>   search path specified by PATH is used to find the directory containing
>   the file. If any arguments arg are specified, they become the
>   positional parameters while processing the . command and the original
>   positional parameters are restored upon completion. Otherwise the
>   positional parameters are unchanged. The exit status is the exit
>   status of the last command executed.

Comment: Thanks @vlp. That worked for me. Thanks for the link also.